# why do we write `abelian` group instead of `Abelian` group?

Tags: mathematics, language

Suppose an object (or a concept or ...) is named after the person `X`, in honor of Mr. or Mrs. X in mathematics: `X`-ian objects/ `X`-ic objects/ `X` objects.

It is natural for me to write the first letter of his/ her name in English in capital letters when referring to that object/ concept. For instance: Gaussian curvature, Newtonian mechanics, Riemannian geometry, Archimedean valuation, Eulerian graph, Platonic solids, Jacobian matrix, Noetherian rings, Artinian rings, Hamiltonian path, Hermitian matrix, Hessian matrix, ...

> But why do we usually write `abelian` group instead of `Abelian` group? Or why do we usually write `abelian` variety instead of `Abelian` variety?

My strong suspicion is that perhaps the importance of abelian groups has reached us through mathematicians in languages other than English. But since I do not have a background in mathematical history, it is very likely that my guess is wrong.

> Is this related to the French school of mathematics? (I know that "variety" is the French equivalent of "Manifold".) If yes, then why do we write Galois extensions?

> Are there any exceptions other than abelian groups?

Also, I do not know what is the suitable tag for my question.

---

---

---

My answer:

I thought that perhaps the word abelian had entered the "ordinary human language", and had been **accepted as an adjective**. (Why did I use the term "**accepted**"? Because **without losing accuracy**, we can **easily** translate this word into "ordinary human language". In some sense, it has **replaced** the word commutative in some areas of the mathematical literature.)

---

That's why I checked [ablian's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abelian) from Merriam-Webster's dictionary, and this hypothesis was reinforced for me. (It states that: "adjective, often capitalized") Also, the status of the word [euclidean](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euclidian) is the same as the status of the word abelian. (It is mentioned again that: adjective, often capitalized) Also, see [platonic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platonic).

When I came here to add my observations to my questions, I saw [Professor K. Conrad's comment](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12664/why-do-we-write-abelian-group-instead-of-abelian-group?noredirect=1#comment25190_12664), in which he introduced an [MO post (Why is “abelian” infrequently capitalized?)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44946/why-is-abelian-infrequently-capitalized), which is exactly the subject. I saw the answers there, and the discussions there were very convincing to me.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but interestingly enough this morning I was writing a bibliographic entry in one of my manuscripts I tinker with, and the paper's title included "abelian group". However, the photocopy of the paper I had wrote the title in all capital letters (e.g. $\ldots$ *ABELIAN GROUP* $\ldots),$ and my policy is to italicize titles, capitalize the first word, then only capitalize any later words if they would nearly always be capitalized. I wasn't sure whether to capitalize abelian, so I looked at some bibliographies in my books and searched online before deciding on 'a'.

Comment: Random thought: It's standard practice for SI units that when a name is used for a unit, it's always lowercase when written out. E.g. amperes, farads, henrys, coulombs. Maybe a similar convention was popular when abelian was coined.

Comment: Some people make up claims like "it's the greatest honor for your name to be lower case as a label" as a way of explaining the small a in abelian, but that strikes me as plain silly.  Anyway, your question has been discussed before at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44946/why-is-abelian-infrequently-capitalized.

Comment: @KCd Yeah, if that were the case, Galois theory would have a small 'g'.

Comment: I find persuasive [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44954/2362) at the above-linked MO question, which suggests that indeed it has to do with in which language the term is popularized. In particular, in French (and perhaps other Romance languages?), adjectives are _never_ capitalized, even when they are derived from a proper name (though apparently this is starting to change under influence from English). So terms like "abelian group", "noetherian ring", etc. end up lower-cased because of French influence in the spread of the terms (they _had_ to be changed to lower-case in French).

Comment: @TimCampion Thanks for your comment.

It seems interesting, and I didn't know this; If so, then we should be able to find more examples, can more examples be found? I just know these examples:  "abelian", "euclidean", "platonic" and "noetherian". And for instance, why do we write "Lagrangian" and not "lagrangian"?

Comment: I think "cartesian" is another example (the adjective form of "Descartes").

Comment: @TimCampion I had never considered this example, thanks for this example.